# Vue Router Blank Page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want a my html template migrate to vue router. I do it. I can view my project with npm run serve code. Not npm run dev. Project created with vue create code. I build this project and index.html blank page. Not console error or any error.

I tried a new vue project with webpack. (vue init webpack project) And give me a link error in main.css file.

Routes.js :

```
 import Home from './components/Home';
export const routes = [
  { path: '/', component : Home , name : 'home', 
  meta: {
      title: 'Web Page',
      metaTags: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'The home page of our example app.'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: 'The home page of our example app.'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

Public/index.html (imported css and js files) : 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- main css file -->
<link href="/css/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body><!-- start body -->
<noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but kriptovue doesn't work properly without 
JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <!-- jquery -->
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- template JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/template-scripts.js"></script>
<!-- flickity JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!-- carousel JavaScript -->
<script src="/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- parallax JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/parallax.min.js"></script>
<!-- mailchamp JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/mailchamp.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap offcanvas -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.offcanvas.min.js"></script>
<!-- touchSwipe JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<!-- ajax mailer -->
<script src="/js/mailer.js"></script>
<!-- seconde style additionel JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/particles-code.js"></script>
<script src="/js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Vue version : 2.9.6 
Vue Router Version : 3.0.6

How can i fix this ?

Comment: What is the "link error"? What *exactly* does it say?

Comment: No error, no data. Only blank page.

Comment: You said "And give me a link error in main.css file." What error is that?

Comment: I tried a new project with vue init webpack projectname code. And i imported css and js files in main.js with require('path') method. It's give me a link error. In main.css font import codes a error.

Comment: And that error says **what**? The exact wording, please.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/icons-pack/electronics/Flaticon.eot' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\vueapp\src\assets\css'
----
in a css file importing flaticon.eot and vue not can do it. i delete this line and give me a another this style error.

Comment: OK, so your build is failing because you don't have the paths right. Fix that.

Comment: You say path is a vue router paths ? if yes i added paths to subject, can u check it ?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with vue-router. Your CSS file has the wrong path to `flaticon.eot`. As your CSS files are processed as part of the build, the failure prevents everything from completing.

Comment: I have a lot of part of my template. How can i do it all css and js files ?